# front end date field format doesn't work? fields[dateField][date]

Tags: form

There are a number of answers on this forum for getting a front-end form to have a DateTime field that splits date and time into separate fields; It's not working for me.

If I strip back to absolute basics - hardcoded, as a test:

`<input type="hidden" id="endDate" name="fields[endDate]" value="2017-12-30 02:15:00" />`

Works, and a date & time is stored in the back-end field, displaying correctly.

But, if I try to split it so the date and time fields are separate (so that I can use a date picker on one and a select drop down on the other) - it doesn't save a value into the field. Even stripped back to hard-coded hidden fields...

`<input type="hidden" id="endDate" name="fields[endDate][date]" value="2017-12-30" />`

`<input type="hidden" id="endTime" name="fields[endDate][time]" value="02:15:00" />`

What am I doing wrong? The is the same format that works in the Craft back-end...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it might be your values. Try testing with this hard coded in and see if it works:

```
<input type="hidden" id="endDate" name="fields[endDate][date]" value="12/30/2017" />
<input type="hidden" id="endTime" name="fields[endDate][time]" value="2:15 AM" />
```

I always reference what's on this [StraightUpCraft](https://straightupcraft.com/articles/craft-cms-field-guide-twig?view=input) guide, and I try to be as *exact* as possible to the examples. You can also just inspect date fields inside a saved entry in the CMS to see what the values look like and mimic that on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did this using a field called `expirDate`:

`<input type="date" name="expiryDate" id="expiryDate" class="form-control">`

Can you give that a try?

Comment: How do you set value?

Comment: I can't rely on a date field type unfortunately as browser support is still spotty, and it wouldn't allow me to select the time either.